# Making a custom scrolling in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vertical-scrolling, custom-scrolling

I would like to force a scroll in javascript so i wrote that script but it doesn't work.
The script makes the user scroll and after his execution, it goes back to the top of the page.

```
function myscroll(i)
{
    if (document.body.scrollTop < i - 100)
    {
        document.body.scrollTop += 10;
        setTimeout(myscroll(i), 10);
    }
}
```

How can i fix that ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Would you mind creating a small example on [jsBin](http://jsbin.com)?

Comment: Here it is http://jsbin.com/AqOlitE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an anonymous function for `setTimeout` to work as you'd expect:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    myscroll(i)
}, 10);
```

Comment: @Copy your welcome. Please accept and/or upvote this answer. ;-) And take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) as you seem to be a new user…